# android studio java.io.filenotfoundexception Save text file

Tags: java, c#, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have copy an example from developer page:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";
FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

but it says that that:

> exception java.io.filenotfoundexception  on : 
>   openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

Comment: I'm guessing you haven't got the permission to access files.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: how can i get the permission?

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In the manifest

More on: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html